# How to filter Material-UI Select component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to have the ability of filtering option list in `Select` component.

Material-UI already have this options in [The Autocomplete component API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api)  (see filterOptions prop) but not in `Select` component.

**Current behavior:**

I have 4 different text fields that using the same `options` list (state),
When I choose one option in one of the text fields I can add him again in the other (3) fields.

**Expected behavior**

When I choose one option in one of the text fields I want this option to be "hidden" \ "removed" in the other text fields.
In addition, When I remove the value from one of the text fields I want him to be available again in the other text fields.

Thank you.

Comment: Please create a working example so we can help.

Comment: Why 4 different `TextField`s? your problem is oddly specific.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Each field is supposed to have different country. My users supposed to choose up to 4 different countries.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another array named `chosenValues` or something like that and add values there if they will be selected. In each `<TextField/>` you can just add filter to options so it will not show values that are in the `chosenValues` array like:

```
 options = { options.filter(x => !chosenValues.includes(x) ) }
```

Comment: This will work only when I'm adding new values each time.
But when I'm removing some value from one of the text fields the value is not returning back to the list.

Comment: Yes because you have to put it back when you delete it

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain three variables , for example lets say

```
// contains the list of all users
 var originalList=[users]

// contains list of unselected users , initally will be originalList
var unselectedList=[]

// contains object of selected users
var selectedFields={textfield1:val, textfield2:val}
```

if user selects a value then remove that user from unselected variable , if he selects different user then add the unselected user from originalList and put back , you can refer to this code sandbox on how to implement it

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]